# Word 2007 - Save as Pdf gives error

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have created a MS Word document in 2007. When I try saving/publishing it in PDF format it gives me the following error:

> The export failed due to an unexpected error

Can someone please guide me on solving this?

I would also like to know whether there is any possibility of the anti virus software installed on my pc being the culprit for this.

Comment: then why not to disable the AV and try again to checkout ;)

Comment: I tried disabling yet it doesnt work :(

Comment: Recommended for migration to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue but after some troubleshooting myself, I found that it was because using custom fonts, try CTRL+A and change all fonts to something like "Arial". If you had header and footer, make sure to change that font as well. Somehow the PDF converter not able to convert if the fonts was not default from Microsoft.